# Waiting for vertical blank in kernel mode?

Tags: windows, kernel, interrupt, wdf, kmdf

I'm writing a driver that needs synchronization with vertical blank interrupt to send some data down the USB pipe.

In user-mode there are Direct X functions available for this like [IDXGIOutput::WaitForVBlank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and few older ones. I am not able to use them from kernel.
I found another interface in Windows 8 SDK: [D3DKMTWaitForVerticalBlankEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which even has a kernel header (the header is in /km/ folder of the SDK), but it requires `gdi32.lib` which a user-mode library and linking  with it cripples the driver.

**Is there any way I can wait or get a notification about vertical blank occurence (without polling)?**

Answer (score 1):

Is it acceptable to have a user mode portion of your driver? You could have a helper process in user mode which waits for the VBI, and have that process trigger your KM driver in some way.

Comment: that's how I do it right now; though I would like to get rid of the overhead of sending IOCTLS down to the driver. I need every microsecond I can get.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named event.

- In your driver create a named event and a kernel thread to wait on the event before doing real work.
- In a user-mode helper app/service open the named event and create a thread to call IDXGIOutput::WaitForVBlank then immediately set the named event.

Of course I'd imagine you worked this out long ago and moved on...